# Adding Data Values to a Search Algorithm?

Tags: java, search, recursion, addition, binary-search

How do I add say 1000, 10000, 1000000, or 10000000 individual data items to a search algorithm?

Code:

```
public class BinarySearch {

int binarySearch(int[] array, int value, int left, int right) {
      if (left > right)
            return -1;
      int middle = (left + right) / 2;
      if (array[middle] == value)
            return middle;
      else if (array[middle] > value)
            return binarySearch(array, value, left, middle - 1);
      else
            return binarySearch(array, value, middle + 1, right);           
}
```

}

Comment: You mean search through different arrays with the same algorithm?

Comment: Your question as stated is not clear.  Do you mean, how do you add more items into the dataset being searched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to try your algorithm with different amounts of integers in your array.

```
public int[] makeArray(int size, int minNum, int maxNum) {
    int [] arr = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();       

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = minNum + r.nextInt(maxNum);
    }

    Arrays.sort(arr);

    return arr;
}
```

So if you want to have 10000 numbers ranging from 100 to 500, then you would call:

```
int[] arr = makeArray(10000, 100, 500);
```

Actually, I recommend making a helper method to start off your searches like so:

```
public int binarySearch(int[] array, int value) {
    return binarySearch(array, value, 0, array.length - 1);
}
```

Then you can look in `arr` for a value (e.g., 5):

```
int i = binarySearch(arr, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are asking how to populate the array. Here is one way to do it:

```
    final Random rnd = new Random();
    final int n = 100000;
    final int[] array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        array[i] = rnd.nextInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(array);
```